# Terminology for the cardinality of the transitive closure of a set.

Tags: set-theory

Let us say that a set $X$ is *transitive* if for all $x \in X$, if $x$ is a set then $x \subseteq X$.

(This is all from a naive set theory perspective; I'm assuming, for instance, that $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is a transitive set because none of its elements are sets.)

Now, let us define the *transitive closure* $T(X)$ of a set $X$ to be the intersection of all transitive sets of which $X$ is a subset. Roughly speaking, the transitive closure of $X$ is $X \cup$ the elements of the elements of $X \cup $ the elements of the elements of the elements of $X$, and so on.

If $T(X)$ is a finite set, then obviously $X$ is a finite set. Moreover, there's a sense in which $X$ is "definitely" a finite set, in a way that e.g. $\{\mathbb{N}\}$ is not, since even though $|\{\mathbb{N}\}| = 1$, we have $|T(\{\mathbb{N}\})| = |\{\mathbb{N}\} \cup \mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$.

With that in mind, is there a standard name (analogous to "the cardinality of $X$") for the cardinality of $T(X)$?

Is there a standard term (analogous to "X is a finite set") for sets $X$ such that $T(X)$ is a finite set?

Comment: The transitive closure of $x$ is finite iff $x\in V_\omega$.

Comment: I should mention that the modern set theory defines the natural numbers as sets starting from the empty set and iterations: for example, $0=\varnothing$, $1=\{0\}$, $2=\{0,1\}$ and so on. Thus the transitive closure of $\{1,2,3\}$ is $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Yes, I know; perhaps I'll edit my question to remove the comment about "naive set theory".

Comment: By the way, the term "transitive closure" is completely standard, so you don't need to put it in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't hear any name of the cardinality of $T(x)$. It is just usually called the cardinality of the transitive closure of $x$. However, if $T(x)$ is countable, $x$ is often called a *hereditary countable set*.

Now I am going to answer your second question:

**Claim.** $T(x)$ is finite if and only if $x\in V_\omega$, where $V_\omega$ is the $\omega$th [von Neumann hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

*Proof.* Note that $V_n$ is transitive for all $n$. If $x\in V_\omega$, then there is some $n<\omega$ such that $x\in V_n$. Since $V_n$ is transitive and $x\in V_n$, $x\subseteq V_n$ and $T(x)\subseteq V_n$, by your definition of the transitive closure. Therefore $T(x)$ is finite.

The proof of the converse uses the induction on the size of $T(x)$: assume that if $|T(y)|<n$ then $y\in V_\omega$. Now assume that $|T(x)|=n$. Note that
$T(x) = x\cup T\left(\bigcup x\right)$ and $x$ is non-empty so $|T(\bigcup x)|< n$ and $T(\bigcup x)\in V_\omega$. From this we have $x\subseteq V_\omega$.
Since $x$ is finite, every element of $x$ lies on for some $V_m$, so $x\in V_{m+1}\subseteq V_\omega$. You can check that $V_\omega$ is closed under finite union therefore $T(x)\in V_\omega$.

This is the reason why the set $V_\omega$ is called the set of *hereditary finite sets*.

---

*Added on 23 April 2020:* Someone asked to me that $|T(\bigcup x)|< n$ in the above proof holds. Here is the proof of it:

We know that $T(x) = x\cup T\left(\bigcup x\right)$. Hence it suffice to prove that $x\nsubseteq T(\bigcup x)$. Since $x$ is finite, we can choose $y\in x$ whose rank is greatest among that of elements of $x$. If $w\in z\in x$, then $\operatorname{rank}w <\operatorname{rank}z\le\operatorname{rank}y$. Hence $y\notin \bigcup x$. By the same argument, we have $y\notin T(\bigcup x)$.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.